# AS2 nextFrame() and gotoAndPlay()

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have made 2 key frames on frame 10 and frame 15, between the frame, I have made a classic tween

I'm trying to play from frame 10 to 15

I have try some method such as nextFrame and gotoAndPlay

for nextFrame, it will play from frame 1 to 15

```
_root.travel.onEnterFrame = function() {
if (mouse_over_travel) {
_root.travel.nextFrame();
} else {
_root.travel.prevFrame();
}
};
```

for gotoAndPlay, it's just play one frame which is frame 10 only

```
_root.travel.onEnterFrame = function() {
if (mouse_over_travel) {
_root.travel.gotoAndPlay(10);
} else {
_root.travel.prevFrame();
}
};
```

I would like when the user hover the button, the animation will play from frame 10 to frame 15
is anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

to play the timeline backwards you will need to loop the previous frame function..flash always plays forward even when you call prev frame, so looping it will allow to play backwards.. you can always compare the frames for equality.

```
 _root.travel.onEnterFrame = function() {
 if (mouse_over_travel && currentFrame == "10") { // i dont know where your code is
      _root.travel.nextFrame();
 if (mouse_over_travel && currentFrame == "15"){ // im guessing here to help you
     _root.travel.gotoandStop(where ever);
 }
 };

  //currentframe you can replace with the path of the symbol frame or what have you.
```